# Can I set jetty classloading semantics using system properties?

Tags: java, jetty

In our project, we start embedded Jetty using only the Java API (no external xml, etc.), and then deploy war bundles to it. Now I have a situation where I'm getting `ClassCastException`s because of differing jars loaded from the `.war` vs. what is on the actual classpath. Reading the Jetty page on classloading (https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html) I wanted to see if I could configure the `WebAppClassLoader` to augment the set of classes considered to be 'system' classes. There is a Java API to do this (`WebAppContext.setServerClasses()`) and a way to do it if you're using an xml config file:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
 <Set name="serverClasses">foo.bar.,com.acme.</Set>
 ...
```

But I'd like to know if it is possible to do it using just Java system properties.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no system properties to configure server or system classes on a WebAppContext.

This is because that kind of change is considered to belong to a specific WebApp, not all WebApps.

But, you have an alternative, if you are using the [`DeploymentManager`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/DeploymentManager.html) in your embedded-jetty, you are in luck, you have an option in code.

You'll want to create a custom [`AppLifeCycle.Binding`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/AppLifeCycle.Binding.html) which sets those properties on any deployed `WebAppContext` (I would recommend binding to `deploying`).

Here's an example that forces the WebAppContext's to always use the logging libraries from the server/system classloader.

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.graph.Node;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class CentralizedWebAppLoggingBinding implements AppLifeCycle.Binding
{
    public String[] getBindingTargets()
    {
        return new String[]
        { "deploying" };
    }

    public void processBinding(Node node, App app) throws Exception
    {
        ContextHandler handler = app.getContextHandler();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("No Handler created for App: " + app);
        }

        if (handler instanceof WebAppContext)
        {
            WebAppContext webapp = (WebAppContext)handler;
            webapp.addSystemClass("org.apache.log4j.");
            webapp.addSystemClass("org.slf4j.");
            webapp.addSystemClass("org.apache.commons.logging.");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's an example of using DeploymentManager from embedded-jetty (with the above `CentralizedWebAppLoggingBinding` too.

```java
ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();

DeploymentManager deployer = new DeploymentManager();
if(debugIsEnabled)
{
    DebugListener debug = new DebugListener(System.err, true, true, true);
    server.addBean(debug);
    deployer.addLifeCycleBinding(new DebugListenerBinding(debug));
}
deployer.setContexts(contexts);
deployer.setContextAttribute(
    "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
    ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$");

WebAppProvider webAppProvider = new WebAppProvider();
webAppProvider.setMonitoredDirName(jettyBase + "/webapps");
webAppProvider.setDefaultsDescriptor(jettyHome + "/etc/webdefault.xml");
webAppProvider.setScanInterval(1);
webAppProvider.setExtractWars(true);
webAppProvider.setConfigurationManager(new PropertiesConfigurationManager());
webAppProvider.addLifeCycleListener(new CentralizedWebAppLoggingBinding());
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Your answer is very helpful - I'll take a look at implementing that in our code.